# Flutter app using in_app_purchases, what to do before rolling out to production?

Tags: flutter, google-play, in-app-purchase, app-store

I have followed the codelabs to integrate in app purchases in flutter here https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-in-app-purchases#0

Also read the official documentation https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase.

I have the app working fine in development. The products are properly fetched from both stores (app store and google play) and test payments are being done in both platforms:

- In  google play, with the test card
- In app store by using the tester account (https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev8b997bee1)

Yet I don't not what else I need to do before rolling the apps into production. I am afraid somehow the test configuration will prevail and actual users will purchase for free on production. I cannot see anywhere a configuration where I could easily turn a switch from test/sandbox to production.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calm down, I also had the same fear, the important thing is to be clear that only authorized users as License Verifiers can buy with a test card, other people can not. (Android)

In the case of iOS is the same only the verifiers that you added will be able to buy with a test card.

It is recommended to leave this permission only to the trusted team.